# Jackson ignore nested properties

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Let's say I have this class that I want to serialize

```
public class FormattedOutput {
    public Filters filters;
    // and more properties, more methods and classes

    public class Filters {
        public Set<Config> configs;
    }
}
```

and this class that should not be edited:

```
public class Config implements Comparable<Config>, Serializable {
    List<Config> children;
    List<Config> fathers;
    Integer somethingElse;

    public getNotAProperty {
        // Jackson parses it, I don't need/want it
        // it actually causes in infinite recursion and i don't need this in my output
    }
}
```

Is there a way, from FormattedOutput to add something along the lines of this?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"filters.configs.fathers", "filters.configs.notAProperty"})
```

Sorry if it is a duplicate of another question, but I didn't find any other answers than using directly @JsonIgnore on Config class elements to ignore...

Comment: Use `@JsonIgnore` on `getFathers` and `getNotAProperty` methods in `Config` class. That's the way to handle this.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I already tried this, and it works, but I wanted to know if there were actually another way. :/

Comment: No as far as I know

Comment: Sadly, There is no plan to add the feature what you want..., 
refer: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2940